# RestTemplate exchange method error: ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for : Connection timed out

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have a problem consuming an REST API with RestTemplate exchange method:

I tried some other public API and it worked with the same code (just changing the URL), so I think it is not a probleme with my code but maybe with the network proxy or something else.

The error text:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for : Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

RestTemplate exchange call:

```
ResponseEntity<FooDto> reponseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(restUrl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, FooDto.class);
```

Comment: You're probably correct. I/O error implies that every is correctly setup. The URL, the http methods, the request body, etc. Only that you cannot connect to the host. You've pretty much answered yourself at this point. What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

The way you define the rest template is crucial here. you need to set the connection time out and read time out.

It is important to optimize them to the level where it doesn't slow down your application responsiveness.

```
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    // Connect timeout: time is in milliseconds
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(3000);
    // Read timeout: time is in milliseconds
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(3000);
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
```